# Create async/await function with Generic Parameter

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to convert my working completions handler functions to the new async/await syntax, but I have a problem finding the right syntax for a function which uses a generic parameter (T):

What I used before and works:

```
typealias CurrentWeatherCompletionHandler = (CurrentWeather?, Error?) -> Void

private func weatherDownload<T: Codable>(weatherType: String, completionHandler completion:  @escaping (_ object: T?,_ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    
    let pathReference = storage.reference(withPath: "\(weatherType)"+"-de.json")
    
    pathReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Error beim \(weatherType) Download: \(error)")
            completion(nil, error)
        } else {
            do {
                let weather = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: data!)
                completion(weather, nil)
            } catch let error {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
}

func getCurrentWeather(completionHandler completion: @escaping CurrentWeatherCompletionHandler) {
    weatherDownload(weatherType: Constants.currentWeatherFolder) { (weather: CurrentWeather?, error) in
        completion(weather, error)
    }
}
```

What I tried, but didn't work:

```
private func weatherDownload<T: Codable>(weatherType: String) async -> (weather: T?, error: Error?) {
   //same network code as before but with return instead of completion:
   return (weather, nil) // Compiler Error: 'nil' requires a contextual type / Unexpected non-void return value in void function
}

func getCurrentWeather() async -> (weather: CurrentWeather?, error: Error?) {
    return await weatherDownload(weatherType: Constans.currentWeatherFolder)
}
```

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Please attach the full code of your networking logic in the async function.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't convert your "same network code as before" to async.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I attached the network code above. It loads data from FirebaseStorage. I couldn't find a async function for getData().

Comment: What's the relation between `weather` and `T` in the function that fails compiling?

Comment: I recommend this article that covers both async/await and generics, and how to implement them together in the same function https://sweettutos.com/leverage-async-await-to-write-better-generic-network-layer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, if the SDK you're using does not support the Concurrency API, the only way you can use it is by calling `withCheckedContinuation` or `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` (for error handling). The problem with your code is either the problem I mentioned, and / or the fact that Swift does not properly infer the `T` type from the return type.
The following pattern should hopefully work for you:

```
private func weatherDownload<T: Codable>(_ type: T.Type, weatherType: String) async throws -> T {
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in 
        // Your original code from before, 
        // with the following difference instead of calling the completion handler:
        ...
        do {
            let weather = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            continuation.resume(returning: weather)
        } catch {
            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
    }
}
```

For more information regarding this pattern, check out these links: [link1](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-continuations-to-convert-completion-handlers-into-async-functions), [link2](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-create-continuations-that-can-throw-errors)

Comment: Thank you for these information. withCheckedContinuation was exactly what I didn't know about, yet.